# .Net references not appering in Winforms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a 3 tier applicaiton, winforms, business and data layers.  I just pulled the projects out of souce control.  My winforms application references business which references data.  I added a reference to my business layer and my winforms project is not seeing the reference.

"Names or type specified in the Imports . . . doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found . . . "

Any Ideas?

I could swear I am doing this right . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind . . . I dropped the project and re-added it.